# WPF bind control size

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, xaml

I have a StackPanel with a list of custom user controlls that I would like to resize. I would like the user to be able to drag a slider and scale the control size up and down.

Is there a way to bind the control width to a slider value? Something similar to:

```
<MyControl Width="{Binding Path=SizeSlider.SelectedValue}"/>
```

Is this possible? Or should I just iterate through the controls and manually set the size whenever the slider value changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this just fine by using

```
<MyControl Width="{Binding ElementName=SizeSlider, Path=Value}"/>
```

By only setting `Path` you assume that something named `SizeSlider` would exist in the current DataContext.

I've done this in code once and it worked:

```
var binding = new Binding("Value") { Source = slider };
BindingOperations.SetBinding(b, WidthProperty, binding);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(b, HeightProperty, binding);
```

So apparently

```
<MyControl Width="{Binding Source=SizeSlider, Path=Value}"/>
```

might be another way to do it.